# Display jquery mobile icon inline

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have two jquery mobile icons displayed at the top of my app. The first one is in the top-left corner. This is good. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to display the second one in the top-right corner. I tried adding a class to the a-tag that was {display: inline;}, but this did not work. Floating it right sends it to the right, but it's not horizontally aligned with the first icon. It displays underneath the first icon.

This is my code:

```
    <a href='#myPanel' class='ui-btn ui-icon-user ui-btn-icon-notext'></a>
    <a href='#myPanel' class='ui-btn ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-notext'></a>
```

Does anybody know if there is a way to display the second one inline, in the top-right corner?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the class `ui-btn-left` to one of the buttons and `ui-btn-right` to the other.

These classes are provided in the jQuery Mobile CSS for this exact purpose.

Comment: Totally worked. Thanks! Do you know if there is a way to increase the size of the icon?